# In a php session

Tags: php, session-variables, session-state

}

put returns between paragraphs
for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
*italic* or **bold**
indent code by 4 spaces
backtick escapes `like _so_`
quote by placing > at start of line
to make links (use https whenever possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have another session that stores the answers as an array, and add to it after each successful post

Something like this could work:

```
 <?php
    $totalQuestions = count($ques);
    $_SESSION['answers'] = $_SESSION['answers'] ?? [];
    // Get current question, default to 1
    $currentQuestion = count($_SESSION['answers']) == $totalQuestions ? 
        $totalQuestions : 
        $_SESSION['answers'] + 1;
?>

<div class='questionHeader'>
    <label>Question <?php echo $currentQuestion ?> of <?php echo $totalQuestions ?></label>
</div>

<br>

<div class='question'>
    <?php echo $ques[$currentQuestion-1] ?>
</div>

Answer: <input type='text' id='answerOneSub' name='answerOneSub'>
<button type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>Submit!</button>
 
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $_SESSION['answers'][] = $_POST['answerOneSub'];
        echo "<br>" . $_SESSION['answerOneSub'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: This seems to work! But when I submit an answer I get an ouput of "Notice: Undefined index: answerOneSub"

Comment: @YokT you could change echo "<br>" . $_SESSION['answerOneSub']; to echo "<br>" . $_POST['answerOneSub'];

Answer (score 0):

You can use [query param](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) like this:

```php
<?php
$page = 1;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
    $page = (int)$_GET["page"];
}

$url = strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '?');
echo "<form method='post' action='" . $url . "?page=" . ($page + 1) . "'>";
echo "<div class='questionHeader'><label>Question [$page] of 6</label></div>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<div class='question'>" . $ques[$page - 1] . "</div>";
echo "<br>";
echo "Answer: ";
echo "<input type='text' id='answerOneSub' name='answerOneSub'>";
echo "<button type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>Submit!</button>";
echo "</form>";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['answerOneSub'] = $_POST['answerOneSub'];
    echo "<br>" . $_SESSION['answerOneSub'];
}
```